# Android NumberPicker setMin/Max

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I try to set min/max on NumberPicker. I have following values:

```
One, Two, Three, Four
```

I set

```
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(1);
```

the picker will display

```
One, Two
```

However when I set

```
picker.setMinValue(1);
picker.setMaxValue(1);
```

it displays `One` but I expect `Two`. I am confused. Why is One displayed instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it displays One but I expect Two. I am confused. Why is One displayed
>   instead?

Because `NumberPicker` works a little different from what you think.

In number picker you set the value with a code like this:

```
numberPicker.setMinValue(7);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(10);
```

Your `NumberPicker` will have the numbers 7, 8, 9, 10. 
Then use [setDisplayedValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues(java.lang.String[])):

```
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"});
```

The `NumberPicker` has the strings "One", "Two", "Three", "Four".

Now change the min value :

```
numberPicker.setMinValue(10);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(10);
```

The `NumberPicker` has the strings "One".

Why is that?

Because there is no correlation from real values and displayed values. As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java#L1920-L1921) of `NumberPicker` this is how the displayed text is calculated:

```
String text = (mDisplayedValues == null) ? formatNumber(mValue) : mDisplayedValues[mValue - mMinValue];
```

So if your min value is 10 and the selected value is 10 the displayed text is the first element of the array.

Returning to your example if you want to display the string "Two" when set min and max value to 1 you need to change the array accordingly:

```
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"Two"});
picker.setMinValue(1);
picker.setMaxValue(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

picker.setMaxValue(2) should give two, if max is 1 how can u expect 2

Comment: Index starts with 0 so for Two index is 1 not 2. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Its not on index actual values !!